# Catch unhandled exception of invisible thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my C++ application i use an activeX component that runs its own thread (or several I don't know). Sometimes this components throws exceptions. I would like to catch these exceptions and do recovery instead of my entire application crashing. But since I don't have access to its source code or thread I am unsure how it would be done.

The only solution I can think of is to run it in its own process. Using something like CreateProcess and then CreateRemoteThread, unsure how it could be implemented.

Any suggestion on how to go about solving this?

Comment: What kind of exceptions does it throw? Are you sure it's not your code that's at fault (i.e. passing invalid data (*especially* pointers) to the component)?

Comment: It can throw various exceptions. Since its an flash activeX component it can throw exceptions depending on what flash file is loaded. I cannot have any control over that.

Comment: It's most commonly access violation exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up an exception filter with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter().

Comment: How will I know from where the exception originated so that I can do proper recovery?

Comment: You can make a core dump, using MiniDumpWriteDump() (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28VS.85%29.aspx) or a stack trace using AfxDumpStack() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahbxfdc5%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello i have a MFC application in which used flash Actve x controller.if i have written the Application level exception SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() its not help full for me. and its crashing the access valilotion excepption,from the call back from activex controller .for button actions its handling correctly with ProcessWndProcException callback method.... my intention i need to catch the exception from both places same. how to throw all unhandled exceptions from any threads in side main process.

Comment: @Srinivas --  This probably should be a new question.  ActiveX is COM (common object module).  COM objects can run in the same process space as the client program (inproc) or in a separate process space (outproc).  Do you know which this is?  If it is outproc, I doubt if there is any way to catch the exception, but COM is not really my speciality.  Does the ActiveX exception propagate accross the marshalling interface?  I would not expect it to do so.  Some code and some proper diagnostics (error messages, stack traces, etc.) would help.

Comment: its not propagating form Interface.just giving acess valition exception.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000007f675aa2292 in MFCDemo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000. with this exception its crashing. and initiating just in debugger.

Comment: @MichaelJ Please go through the follwing link it have the sample code as well

Comment: @MichaelJ https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/issues/detail?id=232&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Opened%20Reporter%20Summary

Comment: @Srinivas -- This doesn't install an exception filter.  It deliberately dereferences a null pointer, and gets the appropriate exception.  I cannot build your code as it has a missing library.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: if some exception code block is placed in call back of Flash shock wave active x controller .its not raising exceptions.i want to throw the exception which can raised from any thread from MY MFC application. weather its from an ActiveX or in side worker thread.its should be throw able. for that what mechanism we should follow? Question is clearly explained with Example of two screen shots.which library its missing.i will update the code ...

Comment: @michalj http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741603/how-to-throw-unhanded-exceptions-from-flash-active-x-controller-callback?noredirect=1#comment31083845_20741603

Comment: @Srinivas -- I've forgoton the library name and I don't have endless time to set it up again.  You should be able to put together a project that builds without external dependencies.  Then I will look at your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43803/discussion-between-srinivas-and-michael-j)

Answer (score 2):

If the ActiveX component is launching its own threads, then there isn't a lot that you can do. You could set a global exception handler and try to swallow exceptions, but this creates a high likelihood that your program state will become corrupted and lead to bizarre "impossible" crashes down the road.

Running the buggy component in a separate process is the most robust solution, as you'll be able to identify and recover from fatal errors without compromising your own program state.

Comment: The question then becomes. How do I create a new process and then inject the code it should run?

Comment: How are you hosting the ActiveX component now? If there is a command-line program that you already know of that can host it for you, then just launch that. Otherwise, you could write a small host of your own that only contains the bare minimum to run what you need. I can't say more than that without knowing the architecture of your application.

Comment: Its a FlashActiveX component which I use to render frames which my application processes. Its hosted using COM and ATL (I wasn't the one that wrote the hosting wrapper and have limited knowledge of its details). I dont know of any command-line program that can host it for me.

If I understand you correctly the only way to accomplish this is through starting an external program?

EDIT: http://casparcg.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/casparcg/Server/Development/trunk/server/producers/flash/
See FlashAxContainer and FlashProducer

Comment: @ronag do you have any idea to solve the following case

Comment: @ronag https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/issues/detail?id=232&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Opened%20Reporter%20Summary