# how to throw unhanded exceptions from flash active x controller callback

Tags: c++, exception, mfc, crash-reports, activexobject

> i have written a application for improve the software quality used the
>   Crashrpt api for windows. i have tried to integrate the api with My
>   application.Basically i m using flash Active x shockwave object class
>   for Loading swf file. if any exception is raised from WinApp its
>   throwing the exceptions able to catch the report.if any kind of
>   Exception is reised in flash call back method.its not able to process
>   and not able to thrown the exception.i tried with
>   ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(OurCrashHandler)
>   ,_set_se_translator(SeTranslator);all mechanisms but i didn't
>   succeeded. and i have describe the more information in following link

---

[enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/issues/detail?id=232&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Opened%20Reporter%20Summary)

in the above link i have uploaded the code and sample test case png also.

please provide the solution for this as soon as possible,

Comment: ActiveX is built on top of COM. COM doesn't allow exceptions to travel across its interface boundary. A valid COM object doesn't expose unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Then whats the way to handle this senario